# Angular 2 sourcemaps are pointing to CSS bundle not to original SCSS files

Tags: angular, sass, compilation, source-maps

I have an Angular 2+ application and I'm building it in development with:

`ng serve --aot --sourcemap --extractCss`

However, `sourcemap` and `extractCss` flags are helping with sourcemaps generation for styles, but they point to the lines in generated CSS bundle not to the lines in the original SCSS source files.

What could be a reason for this? How do I get sourcemaps to point to the original files?

I'm talking about styles stored in a separate SCSS-files, not about the component ones.

I'm using latest `Angular CLI v.1.7.4`.

Answer (score 0):

## Workaround

Just found this thread: [Source map not working for SCSS files #9099](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9099) in the official repo. Still waiting for the solution, however, it looks like the only viable option now is to revert to the `1.6.6` and to apply [this fix](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9099#issuecomment-363324607):

> In `@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/common.js:162`, add a line `devtool: 'source-map',` in the returned common configuration object in the `getCommonConfig()` function:

```js
...
    catch (e) { }
    return {
        devtool: 'source-map', // add this line
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
             ...
```

Also, there is an [automation script](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9099#issuecomment-366968213) proposed, but I've not tried it.